# Global static variable initialised with a call to static class function in c++

Tags: c++, static, global-variables, static-libraries

Not sure how correctly formulate the question but here is the problem.

I have a static lib where I have the following class in a.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
class A{
public:
 void Run() {
  data_.push_back(10);
  std::cout << "size: " << data_.size() << std::endl;
 }
private:
 static std::vector<int> data_;
};
```

a.cpp is as follows:

```
#include "a.h"
std::vector<int> A::data_;
```

And I have another class in b.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
class B
{
  public:
    static std::string Get();
};
```

And b.cpp:

```
#include "b.h"
#include "a.h"
std::string B::Get()
{
  static A a;
  a.Run();
  return "foo";
}
```

Now my main app which is using the above static lib is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

static std::string var1= B::Get();

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  A a;
  a.Run();
}
```

Trying to understand why the output is:

size: 1

size: 1

There should be a single instance of each static data member for the entire class, so there should be a single call to A::data_ constructor. 
Am I hitting ["static initialization order fiasco"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order)? I.e. data_ is not initialised before I use it, but then I should be getting the crash?

And now lets imagine my data_ holds dynamically initialised items (something none POD). How will it be destructed if at the end data_ holds one item, although I've inserted 2?

And that's what actually is happening in my real life code (it sometimes crashes during destruction of data_).

Getting rid of global static ( **static std::string var1= B::Get();** ) solves the problem, but I still want to understand the under the hood problem.

The described case can be reproduced in VS2015 (the real life case is reproducible in gcc 6.2 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I hitting "static initialization order fiasco"?

Most likely.

You can remove the problem by making the `static` data of a class available via a function call. E.g.

```
class A{
public:
 void Run() {
  getData().push_back(10);
  std::cout << "size: " << getData().size() << std::endl;
 }
private:
 static std::vector<int>& getData();
};

std::vector<int>& A::getData()
{
   static std::vector<int> data;
   return data;
}
```

When you do that, `data` will be initialized when `A::getData()` is called the first time. It removes the static initialization order issue completely.

Comment: @R Sahu, yes, indeed your suggestion gets rid of the problem. Although there is one more important detail: if in destructor of a class you need to call any static function, make sure to do the same call in costructor, otherwise it might be already destructed.

Comment: @Tadzys, I don't recall construction and destruction of `static` objects inside functions being a problem at all, If you run into any issues, please start another post with the relevant details.

Comment: @R Sahu, lets say  my getData holds static std::vector<int*>

Comment: @Tadzys, that points to poor design. It's not a good idea to store pointers in static objects. You can come up with convoluted logic to deal with them but avoid them if you can. Use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead.

Comment: @R Sahu, lets say  getData holds static std::vector<int*> and in destructor I want to clean up the vector, but getData() was called prior to constructor (constructor might not be called at all), so you will get either a leak or a crash. My specific solution was to call getData() in constructor (this way I will guarantee that destructor will be called prior to vector destructor). Of course using smart pointers helps to avoid the problem as well.

Comment: @Tadzys, are you talking about deallocating the pointers in the destructor of `A`?

Comment: @R Sahu, yes, destructor of A

Comment: @Tadzys, I wouldn't use that unless you can guarantee that: 1) There is only one instance of `A` **and** 2) The sole instance of `A` is constructed before the `A::getData()` is called.